# How do I remove the 'Quit' action from an application on OSX

Tags: keyboard, applications

I'm looking for a way to remove the 'quit' action from an application, so I personally cannot close it manually (except by force closing (Cmd+opt+esc).

**Case**
*I've got Wunderlist as my personal To-Do list and use it on Full-screen on a second workspace on my Mac. I simply swipe (4fingers) to the left to quickly access my tasks. Too bad I've got a second habit: quitting/closing an application (Cmd+Q) when I'm done. This often results in closing Wunderlist and having to restart the application. Although this ain't a hassle, I think it can be solved*

So I'd simply repeat: Is there a way to protect an application from being closed (perhaps except when force closing, but at least prevented from closing via CMD+Q)?

Perhaps this could be done by removing the keyboard-shortcut from a specific application via Application services via the menubar, but than i'd also be looking for the context of the function name I've to input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In system preferences you can go to **keyboard/shortcuts.**

[image: shortcuts] 
In the list on the left side click: **app shortcuts and create a new shortcut.**
Pick Wunderlist and for menu item pick stop or close wunderlist just type it exactly like it is typed in the menu in wunderlist.
in the last field put a custom key code and save.
 [image: setup]
Like I did for safari
this should do the trick

Comment: Just as I thought. Just wondered what the context of the function should've been, but didn't knew it was just the text as in the menu bar. I'ts solved now, both CMD+Q and CMD+W have been 'removed'. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! "menu title" is indeed a bit cryptic