# How to get to the help input field on OS X in German?

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

There is this nifty little help input field, which I use often as a new Mac user to find the right menu options. It says Command + Shift + ? is the keyboard shortcut to get there, even in the German Apple help pages.

What happens on my German keyboard with German OSX settings is that I already have to press the shift key to get to the question mark. Thus: When I do that, I get the help (Command + ?), not the help input field.

What's the keyboard shortcut to get to the help input field?

Comment: Is this in all apps, or just some? I think that ? is on a shift key in most languages, it's never a single key-press. On a German keyboard it's on shift ß, English it's shift /

Comment: @tetsujin  He's talking about the Finder.  The German keyboard brings up a different thing than the US keyboard, even in the OS in English.  Probably a bug.

Comment: ah, ok @TomGewecke - was just a thought, but my knowledge on non-English keyboards isn't great. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I am actually talking about all apps. Do you English keyboard guys end up in the input field when pressing cmd + shift + /     ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pure chance I found my answer through this post, which is about remapping shortcuts via the settings menu

[How do I remove the 'Quit' action from an application on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130492/how-do-i-remove-the-quit-action-from-an-application-on-osx)

[image: The general settings, which describes the help menu shortcut]

You have to use Cmd + Shift + / to get to the input field! (probably similar for the non German speakers out there)

Sandro

Comment: Is that the same as Cmd + Shift + 7 on a German keyboard?

Comment: Yeap, it is indeed